# How to open a database in asp.net web forms?

Tags: c#, webforms, visual-studio-2013

I need to open a **pre-existing** Database in ASP.NET Web Form with C#. So far all I have managed to find, are tutorial's on how to make a *new* Database and Table's.

If anyone know's how to do this please let me know.

Thanks'

Comment: What kind of database and where is it located?

Comment: It's a SQL Server Express local database.

Comment: We need more details like how you want to "open" it.  Do you want to show the tables in a series of grids perhaps?  Do you want to fetch specific rows of data?  Do you want to write data from the Web Form back to the database? etc

Comment: Sorry about that. I would like to Query the Database and display it on a table or grid. Then I would like to be able to modify, remove or add data from the form to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open a connection to the database.  You will need the proper connection string.  The place to go is [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/).

   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString);
2. Create a command

   ```
    string yourSQL = "SELECT FirstName FROM Employees";
   ```

   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(yourSQL, conn);
3. Do something with it..

   - execute a DataReader
   - fill a table with a DataAdapter

That's the basic pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Add a connection string to web.config and then 
Write the connection code.

The following is a good place to start for the conn string and the code:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But where do I but the connection string in the Web.config file.